# C:Program works fine but with gdb it crashes

Tags: c

I'm new in C and have some problem. Here is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int read_password(FILE *file, char *password, size_t n) {
  fgets(password, n, file);
  password[strcspn(password, "\n")] = '\0';
}

void elevated_shell(){
  gid_t gid = getegid();
  setresgid(gid,gid,gid);
  fflush(stdout);
  system("/bin/bash");
}

void regular_shell(){
  gid_t gid = getgid();
  setresgid(gid,gid,gid);
  fflush(stdout);
  system("/bin/bash");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  char flag[100];
  char password[100];
  FILE *file;

  printf("Hi! Welcome to my secure shell software!\n");

// Read in the root password
  file = fopen("flag.txt", "r");
  if(file == NULL) {
    printf("FAIL: Failed to open the password file\n");
    return -3;
   } else {
      read_password(file, flag, sizeof(flag));
}

// Read in the user's password
  printf("Please enter the password: ");
  fflush(stdout);
  read_password(stdin, password, sizeof(password));


   if(strcmp(flag,password) == 0) {
      printf("Correct! Here's an elevated shell :)\n");
      elevated_shell();
   } else {
       printf("Incorrect! No elevated shell for you >:)\n");
       regular_shell();
   }

}
```

So, I've compiled this file and run. It works fine when I run it directly  but whenever I try to examine memory with gdb it crashes. For example when breakpoint is set at main function and run program is run  fopen function returns Null because program print out 
**FAIL: Failed to open the password file** and quits. Hope you can help.

Comment: Is not opening the expected file a "crash"? Perhaps there is a reason why the file is not found.

Comment: Maybe you're running gdb while being in another directory? The program looks for `flag.txt` in this directory and nothing is found. In this case, the problem wouldn't be related to gdb.

Comment: txt file is in this directory

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code runs fine under gdb or my FreeBSD 10 system (once I have declared `read_password` as `void`, and replaced bash with sh)

Comment: If your program prints "FAIL: Failed to open the password file\n", well then the file could not be opened for some reason, probably because you are not in the correct directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GDB uses the user privileges that runs the program (type whoami to get noticed) not by privileges that the program has.